# Using reference to session data

Tags: php, session

I'm not quite sure what happens here, and before I screw up my session data, maybe someone can explain it to me.

As a user logs in, I create a session for that user. The sessions are created in a special directory using `ini_set('session.save_path',...)` to prevent others from viewing them.

On the page, a background job is called trough an Ajax-request to process some data. For that, I need the session data (I do not need to write anything in the session, only read). So in the background page I call:

```
session_start();
$COPY=&$_SESSION;
session_write_close();
$_SESSION=&$COPY;
```

Now, although the session is closed, the session data is available throughout the entire process.

It looks like the session is behaving normally after closing it in the background job. I can browse the page using the session for other purposes, and even if I put a `sleep(120);` in the background job the main page doesn't stall. But I don't know what really happens.

So, am I right the session isn't used anymore by the background job? Or does PHP create a new session somewhere? And is there any danger the session-data is corrupted in this way?

Comment: If the session is still open for writing, and I call it elsewhere, PHP will wait till the session is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is not destroyed by calling `session_write_close()`. So `$COPY=&$_SESSION;` is not really needed to read session variables.

After calling `session_write_close()`, any manipulation of `$_SESSION` will not be available for the next request. Therefore, there is no way to currupt session data after `session_write_close()`.

PHP does not start a new session after `session_write_close()`.

**Example:** If you continiously refresh the page

```
<pre><?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['t' . time()] = time();
session_write_close();

$_SESSION['p' . time()] = time();
var_export($_SESSION);

?></pre>
```

you will see an increasing number of `t`-timestamps, but only the last `p`-timestamp.